# How to replace a number on a specific line in a text file

Tags: python, text-files

I have made a program that allows a user to input the name and score of a player, however I am not able to update their score. I have to delete the player and type their name and code in again. Is there a way to fix this?

```
# This IF statement will allow the user to write the name and score of the player.
        if choice == "A" or choice == "a":
            save_name = input('Enter your name: ').title()
            save_score = input('Enter your score: ')
            text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
            whole_thing = text_file.readlines()
            text_file.close()
            if len(whole_thing) < 40:
                text_file = open("highscores.txt", "a")
                text_file.write("\n" + save_name + ' | ' + save_score + "\n")
                text_file.close()
            text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
            whole_thing = text_file.read()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print (whole_thing)
            text_file.close()
            
# This ELIF statement will allow the user to delete a player from the text file.
        elif choice == "B" or choice == "b":
            print("These are the current players and their score:")
            text_file = open("highscores.txt", "r")
            whole_thing = text_file.read()
            print(whole_thing)
            text_file.close()
            time.sleep(0.3)
            save_delete = input("Please enter the name of the player you wish to delete: ").title() + " | "
            #print(f"save_delete = {save_delete}")
            with open("highscores.txt", "r") as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                #print(lines)
            with open("highscores.txt", "w") as f:
                for line in lines:
                    if not(line.startswith(save_delete)):
                        f.write(line)
            time.sleep(0.3)
            print("Player has been deleted.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below does what you want, but I would suggest using a JSON file instead. You can load/save a JSON file easily in python. See [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp)

```py
find_me = "Edo Akse"
new_score = 9001


with open("somefile.txt") as infile:
    # this method splits data into list without the 
    # newline character that infile.readlines() would include
    data = infile.read().splitlines()


with open("somefile.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in data:
        player, score = line.split(' | ') # trim the space with the split
        if player == find_me:
            score = new_score
        outfile.write(f"{player} | {score}\n")
```

Comment: So if I import json will the text files load as json files or would i have to write .json instead of .txt

Comment: the extension doesn't matter, the contents do. You will need to adjust your logic to load and save the file as a JSON file, but you can easily convert python's `dict` and/or `list` to JSON files. See the link to w3schools I provided...